# Is there a way to control limited disolve?

Tags: mesh

I have a very high poly set of meshes, (due to my flagrant use of dynotopo while sculpting,) which I would like to decrease the poly count of. Limited dissolve took the poly count of one of the meshes from 130,000 to about 7000. However the mesh fell apart in some areas and I was not even vaguely happy with the result. Is there a way to control the level of limited dissolve or should I be looking at a decimate modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can control limited dissolve

In Edit Mode with all the mesh selected

Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> and you get option limited dissolve

As soon as you click limited dissolve press <kbd>F6</kbd> to open operator panel and adjust the angel and it will lower the verts (See the verts in the top info bar).

[image]